# Adding username/password in SOAPClient : JBOSS-ESB

Tags: jboss-esb

I have a WSDL URL which has security constriants. I need to provide username and password at  header.
After providing these credentials i can send the request .
how can i add username/password using SOAPClient . I did not find any property defined for username password in SOAPClient.

Thanks,
Madhu CM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jboss-esb comes with two SOAPClients, one based in soapUI and the other based in Wise (alas, it seems these guys are not very smart baptizing their classes). So, there are two solutions:

- **soapUI**: you have to inject headers with a transformation of the XML document. You can use the property `smooksTransform` of SOAPClient action.
- **Wise**: you can add a `SOAPHandler` implementation using property `custom-handlers` of SOAPClient action.